# how to have drawable image filled the entire screen in a ListView in Android?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-drawable

Hi guys I want to have an image that I got from the Vector Asset tab to filled the entire screen on my GridView items. Currently,[it looks like this at the moment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUSwG.jpg). I want to have all my TextViews and ImageView to be inside of this if possible.

Here is the necessary code

This is the XML layout that my GridView currently adapts and inflate with. Look at the top part of the code to save time to see the --> android:background="@drawable/ic_folder_white_24dp">

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_folder_white_24dp">
<!--    android:background="@drawable/text_view_border">-->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/check_box"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date_created"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:gravity="center" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:gravity="center"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/desc"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_height="250dp" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/psw_lock"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_lock_black_24dp"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my GridView code in my mainActivity.xml though I don't think its revelant

```
<GridView
            android:id="@+id/grid_view"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="12dp"
            android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
            android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
            android:numColumns="2">
        </GridView>
```

Lastly here is my drawable image itself. I try messing with the values though nothing points to the right direction. By default it got me 24dp.

```
<vector android:height="24dp" android:tint="#FFDF00"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0" android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:width="24dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path android:fillColor="#FF000000" android:pathData="M10,4H4c-1.1,0 -1.99,0.9 -1.99,2L2,18c0,1.1 0.9,2 2,2h16c1.1,0 2,-0.9 2,-2V8c0,-1.1 -0.9,-2 -2,-2h-8l-2,-2z"/>
</vector>
```

Any help would be appreciative.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want a folder on each grid item, with all the other views inside it, you'll need to set some padding on the item's layout or margins on its views, so they don't overlap the edges. Whatever works to fit the image!

If you mean you want one big folder as the entire background, you'll need to set that as the background to the `GridView` area in your activity's layout file. So it's the background of the whole grid container, not separate backgrounds for each item.

Also I don't think you can avoid the background being stretched to fit the view, so you'll probably need to add an `ImageView` with `scaleType="fitCenter"` or something (and you won't be able to use a `LinearLayout` to overlay something on that image)